Filter deserialized results on a specific value from array of JSON objects?
I am getting JSON responses from API:
"table1": [
    {
        "abc": "test",
        "def": "test1"
    },
    {
        "abc": "test2",
        "def": "User1"
    }       
]

which is binding into
public List<object>? table1 { get; set; }

I want to get the User1 using Linq/Lamda.
Below returns 0 record:
    var filteredList = table1
        .Where(item => 
        item.GetType().GetProperty("def",BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase)?.GetValue(item)?.ToString() is "User1" or "User2")
.ToList();

What is wrong with it

I don't see why you attempt with System.Reflection and pattern matching is here.
Either with the help of the JSON library such as Newtonsoft.Json to read/parse the object's field:
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

string[] filters = new string[] {"User1", "User2"};
var filteredList = table1
    .Where(item => filters.Contains(JObject.FromObject(item)?.SelectToken("def").ToString()))
    .ToList();

Or if you know the structure of your Table object, you define and use the model class instead of object type:
public class Root
{
    public List<Table>? table1 { get; set; }
}

public class Table
{
    public string Abc { get; set; }
    public string Def { get; set; }
}

string[] filters = new string[] {"User1", "User2"};
var filteredList = table1
    .Where(item => filters.Contains(item.Def))
    .ToList();


Thanks Linq is working perfectly fine

Demo @ .Net Fiddle

The problem is that "System.Object" does not expose any properties that the serialization framework can bind to. They would not exist for filtering.
One simple option is to use dynamic type, which the serialization framework in your example has explicit support for (via ExpandoObject):
public List<dynamic> table1 { get; set; }

Then your filter list could look something like this:
    var filteredList = table1
        .Where(item =>
            "User1".Equals(item.def)
            || "User2".Equals(item.def))
        .ToList();

This would minimally change your example.
It would be ideal to use explicit type definitions to avoid late-binding issues, such as not receiving a def value, but if you are specifically trying to late-bind to data then dynamic should fit your need.
